# ASP.NET: How to redirect without changing URL in the Browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im part of a team creating a server project in ASP.NET that provides a series of services to logged in members. We separated the server into components such as for authentication. Example of components are seen in the table below. This way its helps manage the project in terms of testing and other benefits.

```
+-----------------+-------------------+
|    Component    |      Address      |
+-----------------+-------------------+
| Authentication  | 192.168.0.10:5001 |
| User Management | 192.168.0.10:5002 |
| Search Engine   | 192.168.0.10:5003 |
| System Settings | 192.168.0.10:5004 |
+-----------------+-------------------+
```

The issue we are facing is that we want to to use only one url in the browser just like in the table below. We have already matched **subdirectories** with their respective **component**. For example, `/login` should redirect to `Authentication` component. If a user has navigated to the search page and entered a search term, it should redirect from `www.mysite.com/search?value=test` to `192.168.0.10:5003?value=test`.

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|           ULR           |     Redirect      |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
| www.mysite.com/         | 192.168.0.10:5000 |
| www.mysite.com/login    | 192.168.0.10:5001 |
| www.mysite.com/users    | 192.168.0.10:5002 |
| www.mysite.com/search   | 192.168.0.10:5003 |
| www.mysite.com/settings | 192.168.0.10:5004 |
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

How to program a separate project as gateway in C# ASP.NET to intercept and receive any url path without controllers and redirect to the component without changing the URL in the browser?

Comment: This is still in preview but I recommend you to check out YARP project: https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy

Comment: It's promising. I tried it and it worked for a simple redirection. But getting it to work for multiple destinations will be a bit tricky. Thanks Artur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a middleware for handle your request:

this middleware  get request and send it to other application and get that response and forward to first one.

just sample for idea:

```
  public class Startup
    {
         
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api"))
                {     
                   
                    string BaseUrl = (env.IsDevelopment() ? "172.0.0.1:5001" : "192.168.0.10:5001") + context.Request.Path.Value + (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue ? context.Request.QueryString.Value : "");

                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        //handle Ssl 
                        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
                        SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true),
                    };

                    //handle compression
                    if (handler.SupportsAutomaticDecompression)
                    {
                        handler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip |
                                                         DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
                    }

                    //handle Ssl 
                    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;

                    var client = new HttpClient(handler);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

                    //handle Authorization Header 
                    if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                    {
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString());
                    }
                     
                    // forward User-Agent
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());

                      

                    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                    if (context.Request.Method == "GET")
                    {
                        response = await client.GetAsync(BaseUrl);
                    }

                    if (context.Request.Method == "POST")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            string documentContents;
                            using (Stream receiveStream = context.Request.Body)
                            {
                                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                                {
                                    documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                                }
                            }

                          //  HttpContent content = new StringContent(documentContents, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                            response = await client.PostAsync(BaseUrl, content);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            await context.Response.WriteAsync(e.Message, Encoding.UTF8);
                        }
                    }

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var header in response.Content.Headers)
                        {
                            StringValues stringValues = StringValues.Empty;
                            foreach (var values in header.Value)
                            {
                                StringValues.Concat(stringValues, values);
                            }

                            context.Response.Headers.Add(header.Key, stringValues);
                        }

                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

                        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync(body, Encoding.UTF8);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    await next.Invoke();
                }
            });

        
        }
    }
```

I think you must separate base on path to separate destination.

Comment: Hi @foadabd. It looks good. I will check it out shortly.

Comment: It works but some resources not showing. I continue to make it to work. Thanks foadabd.

Comment: maybe you must be add more method support like : if (context.Request.Method == "HEAD") .